# Out of Memory with RAY Python Framework

Tags: numpy, memory-management, multiprocessing, python-3.7, ray

I have created a simple remote function with ray that utilizes very little memory.  However, after running for a short period of time the memory increases steadily and I get a RayOutOfMemoryError Exception.

The following code is a VERY simple example of this problem.  The  "result_transformed" numpy array is being sent to the workers where each worker can do work on this.  My simplified calc_similarity function does nothing, but it still runs out of memory.  I have added much longer sleep times to that method to simulate doing more work, but it eventually runs out of memory.

I am running on an 8-core Intel 9900K with 32GB of RAM and Ubuntu 19.10
Python is:  Intel Python Distribution 3.7.4
numpy is 1.17.4  (with intel mkl)

```
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
import ray
import psutil

@ray.remote
def calc_similarity(sims, offset):
    # Fake some work for 100 ms.
    sleep(0.10)
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Initialize RAY to use all of the processors.
    num_cpus = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)
    ray.init(num_cpus=num_cpus)

    num_docs = 1000000
    num_dimensions = 300
    chunk_size = 128
    sim_pct = 0.82

    # Initialize the array
    index = np.random.random((num_docs, num_dimensions)).astype(dtype=np.float32)
    index_array = np.arange(num_docs).reshape(1, num_docs)
    index_array_id = ray.put(index_array)

    calc_results = []

    for count, start_doc_no in enumerate(range(0, num_docs, chunk_size)):
        size = min( chunk_size, num_docs - (start_doc_no) + 1 )
        # Get the query vector out of the index.
        query_vector = index[start_doc_no:start_doc_no+size]
        # Calculate the matrix multiplication.
        result_transformed = np.matmul(index, query_vector.T).T
        # Serialize the result matrix out for each client.
        result_id = ray.put(result_transformed)

        # Simulate multi-threading extracting the results of a cosine similarity calculation
        for offset in range(chunk_size):
            calc_results.append(calc_similarity.remote(sims=result_id, offset=offset ))
            # , index_array=index_array_id))
        res = ray.get(calc_results)
        calc_results.clear()
```

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After a bit more analysis, it is the line below that is cause the memory usage to increase:

result_id = ray.put(result_transformed)

This value is getting created and is fairly large (typically a numpy ndarray of shape( 300, 1+ million)

Comment: I found that if I periodically call gc.collect() that it free's up the memory and things keep moving along.  I'm guessing that the memory is not being freed up due to weird reference counting due to the way the data is shared in memory.  I read the doc's on ray but did not see anything that directly addresses this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, Ray supports reference counting partially. (Full reference counting will be released soon). Simply put, when the object_id passed to the remote function is not serialized, it is referenced counted in the same way Python is referenced counted. It means if `result_transformed` is garbage collected by Python, the `result_transformed` in the plasma store should be unpinned, and when the object is LRU evicted, it should be evicted. (For the clarity, pinned objects which has some reference counts are not evicted).

I also assume there is some weird reference counting such as circular references. I could verify that `result_transformed` was evicted when I ran this script. So, I guess `result_transformed` itself is not a problem. There can be many possible problems. For my case, I found that ipython creates a reference to python objects when I use it for input (IN). (E.g. when you see the value of some object, OUT[number] can have a reference to your object).

```
In [2]: import psutil 
   ...: import gc 
   ...: import ray 
   ...: from time import sleep 
   ...: import numpy as np 
   ...: @ray.remote 
   ...: def calc_similarity(sims, offset): 
   ...:     # Fake some work for 100 ms. 
   ...:     sleep(0.10) 
   ...:     return True 
   ...:  
   ...: if __name__ == "__main__": 
   ...:     # Initialize RAY to use all of the processors. 
   ...:     num_cpus = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False) 
   ...:     ray.init(num_cpus=num_cpus) 
   ...:  
   ...:     num_docs = 1000000 
   ...:     num_dimensions = 300 
   ...:     chunk_size = 128 
   ...:     sim_pct = 0.82 
   ...:  
   ...:     # Initialize the array 
   ...:     index = np.random.random((num_docs, num_dimensions)).astype(dtype=np.float32) 
   ...:     index_array = np.arange(num_docs).reshape(1, num_docs) 
   ...:     index_array_id = ray.put(index_array) 
   ...:  
   ...:     calc_results = [] 
   ...:     i = 0 
   ...:     for count, start_doc_no in enumerate(range(0, num_docs, chunk_size)): 
   ...:         i += 1 
   ...:         size = min( chunk_size, num_docs - (start_doc_no) + 1 ) 
   ...:         # Get the query vector out of the index. 
   ...:         query_vector = index[start_doc_no:start_doc_no+size] 
   ...:         # Calculate the matrix multiplication. 
   ...:         result_transformed = np.matmul(index, query_vector.T).T 
   ...:         # Serialize the result matrix out for each client. 
   ...:         result_id = ray.put(result_transformed) 
   ...:         if i == 1: 
   ...:             # The first result_id binary number should be stored in result_id_special 
   ...:             # In this way, we can verify if this object id is evicted after filling up our  
   ...:             # plasma store by some random numpy array 
   ...:             # If this object id is not evicted, that means it is pinned, meaning if is  
   ...:             # not properly reference counted. 
   ...:             first_object_id = result_id.binary() 
   ...:         # Simulate multi-threading extracting the results of a cosine similarity calculation 
   ...:         for offset in range(chunk_size): 
   ...:             calc_results.append(calc_similarity.remote(sims=result_id, offset=offset )) 
   ...:             # , index_array=index_array_id)) 
   ...:         res = ray.get(calc_results) 
   ...:         calc_results.clear() 
   ...:         print('ref count to result_id {}'.format(len(gc.get_referrers(result_id)))) 
   ...:         print('Total number of ref counts in a ray cluster. {}'.format(ray.worker.global_worker.core_worker.get_all_reference_counts())) 
   ...:         if i == 5: 
   ...:             break 
   ...:     # It should contain the object id of the  
   ...:     print('first object id: {}'.format(first_object_id)) 
   ...:     print('fill up plasma store by big numpy arrays. This should evict the first_object_id from the plasma store.') 
   ...:     print('because if the data_transformed is garbage collected properly, it should be unpinned from plasma store') 
   ...:     print('and when plasma store is filled by numpy array, first_object_id should be evicted.') 
   ...:     for _ in range(40): 
   ...:         import numpy as np 
   ...:         ray.put(np.zeros(500 * 1024 * 1024, dtype=np.uint8)) 
   ...:     print('total ref count from a ray cluster after eviction: {}'.format(ray.worker.global_worker.core_worker.get_all_reference_counts())) 
   ...:     # this should fail as first_object_id is already evicted 
   ...:     print(ray.get(ray.ObjectID(first_object_id))) 

[ray] Forcing OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 to avoid performance degradation with many workers (issue #6998). You can override this by explicitly setting OMP_NUM_THREADS.
2020-02-12 00:10:11,932 INFO resource_spec.py:212 -- Starting Ray with 4.35 GiB memory available for workers and up to 2.19 GiB for objects. You can adjust these settings with ray.init(memory=<bytes>, object_store_memory=<bytes>).
2020-02-12 00:10:12,273 INFO services.py:1080 -- View the Ray dashboard at localhost:8265
2020-02-12 00:10:18,522 WARNING worker.py:289 -- OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 is set, this may slow down ray.put() for large objects (issue #6998).
ref count to result_id 1
Total number of ref counts in a ray cluster. {ObjectID(ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100008002000000): {'local': 1, 'submitted': 0}, ObjectID(ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100008001000000): {'local': 1, 'submitted': 0}}
ref count to result_id 1
Total number of ref counts in a ray cluster. {ObjectID(ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100008003000000): {'local': 1, 'submitted': 0}, ObjectID(ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100008001000000): {'local': 1, 'submitted': 0}}
ref count to result_id 1
Total number of ref counts in a ray cluster. {ObjectID(ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100008001000000): {'local': 1, 'submitted': 0}, ObjectID(ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100008004000000): {'local': 1, 'submitted': 0}}
ref count to result_id 1
Total number of ref counts in a ray cluster. {ObjectID(ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100008001000000): {'local': 1, 'submitted': 0}, ObjectID(ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100008005000000): {'local': 1, 'submitted': 0}}
ref count to result_id 1
Total number of ref counts in a ray cluster. {ObjectID(ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100008006000000): {'local': 1, 'submitted': 0}, ObjectID(ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100008001000000): {'local': 1, 'submitted': 0}}
first object id: b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x00\x00\x80\x02\x00\x00\x00'
fill up plasma store by big numpy arrays. This should evict the first_object_id from the plasma store.
because if the data_transformed is garbage collected properly, it should be unpinned from plasma store
and when plasma store is filled by numpy array, first_object_id should be evicted.
total ref count from a ray cluster after eviction: {ObjectID(ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100008006000000): {'local': 1, 'submitted': 0}, ObjectID(ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100008001000000): {'local': 1, 'submitted': 0}}
2020-02-12 00:10:57,108 WARNING worker.py:1515 -- Local object store memory usage:
num clients with quota: 0
quota map size: 0
pinned quota map size: 0
allocated bytes: 2092865189
allocation limit: 2347285708
pinned bytes: 520000477
(global lru) capacity: 2347285708
(global lru) used: 67.0078%
(global lru) num objects: 4
(global lru) num evictions: 41
(global lru) bytes evicted: 21446665725

2020-02-12 00:10:57,112 WARNING worker.py:1072 -- The task with ID ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100 is a driver task and so the object created by ray.put could not be reconstructed.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnreconstructableError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-184e5836123c> in <module>
     63     print('total ref count from a ray cluster after eviction: {}'.format(ray.worker.global_worker.core_worker.get_all_reference_counts()))
     64     # this should fail as first_object_id is already evicted
---> 65     print(ray.get(ray.ObjectID(first_object_id)))
     66 

~/work/ray/python/ray/worker.py in get(object_ids, timeout)
   1517                     raise value.as_instanceof_cause()
   1518                 else:
-> 1519                     raise value
   1520 
   1521         # Run post processors.

UnreconstructableError: Object ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100008002000000 is lost (either LRU evicted or deleted by user) and cannot be reconstructed. Try increasing the object store memory available with ray.init(object_store_memory=<bytes>) or setting object store limits with ray.remote(object_store_memory=<bytes>). See also: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/memory-management.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the great analysis.  I actually found out what the exact issue is and how to work around it.  You are correct that the reference counting is preventing the items from being collected.  The "ray.put( result_transformed )" is creating large objects.  The gc thresholds are set high enough that we run out of memory before the GC is actually run.  

I have added coded to check the percent memory free (using psutil.virtual_memory()) and call the gc.collect() if it exceeds 80%. That has resolved my issue.  I could try to change the gc.thresholds() but the settings are task dependent.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped :)  Did you intentionally set the gc thresholds higher than your machine? Or is the default threshold happen to be higher than 32GB machine memory?

Comment: The GC thresholds are based upon # of objects (not size in memory). The default values were high enough that it ran out of memory before the gc ever ran.

Comment: Ray currently support full distributed ref counting, so this issue shouldn't exist anymore!

Comment: What is LRU....?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Sang for you response.

The issue is that the gc is not running because the thresholds that are default are not being reached before I run out of memory on my 32GB system.

The call to ray.put( transformed_result ) can be a fairly large amount of memory (In the example it is 128 x 1,000,000) or about .5 GB of memory using float32.

To work-around this, I created a method that does the following where I can pass in a percentage of memory used threshold and force a call to the garbage collection:

```
def auto_garbage_collect(pct=80.0):
    if psutil.virtual_memory().percent >= pct:
        gc.collect()
```

Call this on a frequent basis in my core processing loops resolves the out of memory condition.

The situation could be also be resolved by modifying the threshold settings in the garbage collection.

```
gc.set_threshold()
```

This is very task dependent and depends upon the size of the data objects being used so I felt the first method was the better choice.

Sang, Thanks for your detailed response! It was very helpful and enlightening.

Comment: Could this be turned into a callback for use in tune etc.?